# JSF 2.0 Submit Form With IncludeViewParams (Ignoring Empty Parameters)

Tags: forms, parameters, get, jsf-2

Is it possible to submit a JSF 2.0 Form using GET without including those parameters that are empty?

```
    <h:form>
      <h:InputText value="#{bean.item}" id="item">
      <h:commandButton value="Submit" 
         action="submit?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"/>
    </h:form>
```

If item is not an empty string, the request is

```
/submit.jsf?item=test
```

But if item is an empty string, the request is

```
/submit.jsf
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<h:form>
  <h:InputText value="#{bean.item}" id="item">
  <h:commandButton value="Submit" 
     action="#{bean.checkparam}"/>
</h:form>
```

bean is

```
    public String checkparam(){
 if(bean.getItem =! null){
return "/submit?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true";
   }else{ 
 return "/submit.jsf"
    }
   }
```